# Nivo Slider with Round Corners - Need to remove white corners!

Tags: css, rounded-corners

I love the NIVO SLIDER, but I want to use it with round corners with CSS3. I can't get rid of the white corners.  Here is the link:  [link text](http://www.ubspack.com)

Is there a better slider that will work with round corners or is there a way to remove or hide the white corners?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://blog.songbirdnest.com/2008/03/14/moz-border-radius-clips-background-images-now-yay/

Recent browsers can clip background images, which Nivo uses, with border-radius.

```
-moz-border-radius: 8px; /* FF1+ */
-webkit-border-radius: 8px; /* Saf3-4 */
border-radius: 8px; /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Saf5, Chrome */
```

Unfortunately, ≤IE8 users will be left out of the dust.

The best solution is to simply just convert these images to PNG and use a transparent background, or make sure the background matches the HTML colors (that's what the issue is with those 'corners').